# Postgresql check constraint: reinspection within 5 years from inspection date

Tags: postgresql, constraints, intervals, date-range

Hi I am new to SQL so please bear with me.

I am trying to set a field constraint on a date field that restricts the user to entering a date that falls within five years into the future of the date, entered into another field.

I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE inspection
ADD CONSTRAINT check_reinspection_date CHECK(dateforreinspection = dateofinspection + interval '5 year')
```

However, this restricts the user to only being able to enter in a date for reinspection that falls exactly five years after the inspection date. I want to restrict the field so that it will allow any date that fall within (but not outside )the first five years of the date for the inspection (ex. day 1 to year 5) 
-But I can't seem to find any information on how to do that, and would therefore be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I'd say that the constraint should look like that:

```
CHECK (age(dateforreinspection, dateofinspection)
       BETWEEN INTERVAL '1 day' AND INTERVAL '5 years')
```